# All paths open a single page

Tags: django, django-urls

I am new to Django and doing something wrong. I've tried many templates and examples and always run into the same problem. No matter what path I try to use, I get the same file.

Settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    #my apps
    'strategicplan.apps.StrategicplanConfig',
    'house.apps.HouseConfig',
]
```

Main site urls.py

```
from strategicplan import views as sp_views
from house import views as house_views



urlpatterns = [
    path('house/',house_views.index),
    path('strategicplan/',sp_views.index),

   ]
```

house/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from house import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

house/templates/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  {% block title %}<title>Houses</title>{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
house 
</body>
</html>
```

strategicplan/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from strategicplan import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('strategicplan/', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

strategicplan/templates/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  {% block title %}<title>strategic plan</title>{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
strategic plan 
</body>
</html>
```

No matter what I put in the url http://127.0.0.1 or http://127.0.0.1/house or http://127.0.0.1/stategicplan, I get the strategicplan/index.html page. Both http://127.0.0.1 and http://127.0.0.1/house end up with http://127.0.0.1 in the address bar, but still show the strategicplan page. The http://127.0.0.1/strategicplan page holds the correct address in the address bar, which is also the correct page.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use this `path('house/',house_views.index)` in urlpatterns, while visiting the route `house/` instead of using the urlspatterns in your `house` app's `urls.py` file, django will simply call the `index()` view function of the `house` app. Same applies for the `strategicplan` app.

Instead your project level `urls.py` file should be

```
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('house/', include('house.urls')),
    path('strategicplan/', include('strategicplan.urls'))
]
```

Comment: I appreciate your quick response. I must have something else wrong. The root no longer works (which is correct), but the house still pulls strategicplan. ```from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('house/', include('house.urls')),
    path('strategicplan/', include('strategicplan.urls'))

]```

Comment: I also tried to add the path to the main index page. I added a templates folder to the main site, then added path('', views.index, name='index'), with a similar index page as the others. I am still getting the strategicplan page (but, without the address bar saying house)

Comment: Change your template directory structure to `app_name/templates/app_name` (i.e) `house/templates/house/index.html`. Then in your `views.py` return this `return render(request, 'house/index.html')`